# CharsetICU java example for char set conversion

Tags: java, character-encoding, icu

I need to convert a file from EBCDIC (IBM 937) to UTF-8. Any idea how I can use the CharsetICU (icu4j API) for charset conversion?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use external libraries to do this conversion (exception handling omitted):

```
Reader r = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(...), "IBM937");
Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOuputStream(...), "UTF-8");

char[] buf = new char[65536];
int size = 0;

while ((size = r.read(buf)) != -1)
    w.write(buf, 0, size);

r.close();
w.close();
```

Comment: tried this already. It doesn't do the coversion right for some reason.
output should be like this:
僔働咗卆匜叀卼卋卆卐
instead its showing like this:
ＶＰそあじょほいあお

Comment: @SNL: It looks very strange. According to http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/5350/charset_support.htm, U+5350 卐 can't be represented in IBM 937 at all. Are you still sure your input is IBM 937? Can you show its hex representation?

Comment: that's right, i'm also double checking with the transmitter. We have a file in ebcdic and another version sent in utf-8. 
Do you happen to know if the hex values remain same between various encodings?

Answer (score 1):

Think you should be able to use CharsetICU.[forNameICU](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/charset/CharsetICU.html#forNameICU%28java.lang.String%29)("ibm-937")  then you can pass the resulting Charset into a reader/writer.

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT a charset conversion, this is a "transliteration" example using ICU library.

Version: ICU4J 53.1

Package: com.ibm.icu.text.Transliterator

```
Transliterator.getInstance("Latin-ASCII").transliterate("Your text");
```

Where: "Latin-ASCII" is the "set of characters" you need (IMPORTANT: this is NOT an encoding). You could check the available IDs using Transliterator.getAvailableIDs();

For "Latin-ASCII":

```
 Given "123" returns "123"
 Given "abc" returns "abc"
 Given "Š Œ ñ" returns "S OE n"
```